# numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided resulting typecasts and random values

Tags: python, numpy, sliding-window, stride

I am generating sliding windows using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` 
using the following

```
wsize=4
overlap=0
vector=np.array(range(31))
fillval=np.nan

part_to_fill=np.full(wsize - (vector.shape[0] - 1) % wsize - 1,fillval)
a_ext = np.concatenate(( vector,part_to_fill))
n = a_ext.strides[0]
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided   
res=strided(a_ext, shape=(vector.shape[0],wsize), strides=(n,n))[[np.arange(0,len(vector),wsize-overlap)],:]
```

if `overlap=0` is all fine and I get

```
array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
        [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
        ..., 
        [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.],
        [ 24.,  25.,  26.,  27.],
        [ 28.,  29.,  30.,  nan]]])
```

however if `overlap=1` is all fine and I get the following, which is unexpected because:

- results are casted to float
- contains random numbers instead of the expected nans e.g.  -3.25951556e-311

  ```
  array([[[  0.00000000e+000,   1.00000000e+000,   2.00000000e+000,
         3.00000000e+000],
      [  3.00000000e+000,   4.00000000e+000,   5.00000000e+000,
         6.00000000e+000],
      [  6.00000000e+000,   7.00000000e+000,   8.00000000e+000,
         9.00000000e+000],
      ..., 
      [  2.40000000e+001,   2.50000000e+001,   2.60000000e+001,
         2.70000000e+001],
      [  2.70000000e+001,   2.80000000e+001,   2.90000000e+001,
         3.00000000e+001],
      [  3.00000000e+001,               nan,   0.00000000e+000,
        -3.25951556e-311]]])
  ```

even if I cast the results back to int using

```
res.astype(int)
```

I get the following which might be even worse

```
array([[[          0,           1,           2,           3],
        [          3,           4,           5,           6],
        [          6,           7,           8,           9],
        ..., 
        [         24,          25,          26,          27],
        [         27,          28,          29,          30],
        [         30, -2147483648,           0,           0]]])
```

Comment: `wsize - (vector.shape[0] - 1) % (wsize - overlap) - 1`

Comment: Note that casting to float happens also in the first case (see the dot after the numbers) because integer data types cannot represent NaN. The "random" numbers are uninitialized memory.

Comment: wsize - (vector.shape[0] - 1) % (wsize - overlap) - 1 is not working yet, please give it a try with wsize =5 shape =23 overlap =2

Comment: `a_ext is float because of the float `nan` addition.  If the striding adds other random values you haven't got the fill right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.nan` is a float.  Concatenating that to an integer array produces a float array.

```
In [101]: x = np.arange(5)

In [102]: np.concatenate((x, np.full(3, np.nan)))   # x1=...
Out[102]: array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,  nan,  nan,  nan])

In [106]: n=x1.strides[0]
In [107]: strided(x1, shape=(5,3), strides=(n,n))
Out[107]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  3.,   4.,  nan],
       [  4.,  nan,  nan]])
```

If I didn't pad it with enough `nan` I would have gotten 'random' values in those extra slots.  This part of why `as_strided` is advanced, and potentially dangerous.

I don't see why you are applying that `overlap` via indexing after striding.  Here's how I'd do the overlap by adjusting the strides:

```
In [110]: strided(x1, shape=(5,3), strides=(2*n,n))
Out[110]: 
array([[  0.00000000e+000,   1.00000000e+000,   2.00000000e+000],
       [  2.00000000e+000,   3.00000000e+000,   4.00000000e+000],
       [  4.00000000e+000,               nan,               nan],
       [              nan,               nan,               nan],
       [              nan,               nan,   2.59784163e-306]])
```

Oops, I've asked for too big of an array (or not padded enough):

```
In [112]: strided(x1, shape=(3,3), strides=(2*n,n))
Out[112]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  4.,  nan,  nan]])
```

---

Your code adds a single `nan` fill.  Let's change that to 10 (just a convenient larger number).  And calculate without the indexing (to get all strided rows):

```
In [123]: res.shape
Out[123]: (31, 4)

In [124]: res
Out[124]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       ...
       [ 27.,  28.,  29.,  30.],
       [ 28.,  29.,  30.,  nan],
       [ 29.,  30.,  nan,  nan],
       [ 30.,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Now you can select every n-th row, without any funny values (except for the float `nan`).

So `as_strided` requires a proper strides, proper shape, and proper padding.

Comment: nice answer thanks. very useful so the second part. obiously I have misused strides by obtaining the overlap via indexing. could you please add how to do it correctly in a general form